# Speed up the android emulator time

Tags: android, testing, time, android-emulator

Is there a way to make the android emulator time go faster? eg. 10x.

I need this for testing purposes.

EDIT: i run my emulator on 4ghz with haxm and gpu emulation enabled, so the speed nor smoothness of the emulator itself is not of a problem. instead, id like to know, how can i make the time in the virtual machine going faster, literally, how to make the minutes  passing faster than real :). the thing is i would like to simulate whole day for my app.

Answer (score 2):

The closest i can think of for you to do this is to change the date and time, to do this you can run the date command on the phone. To do this you will have to run the following command:

adb shell date -s "yyyymmdd.[[[hh]mm]ss]"

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but depending on the design of your app, you might be able to drive it completely externally from an android device or emulator.

I can see this being not too difficult if your app's design was modular.  In this case you should be able to fabricate some drivers that accelerate time for the particular module who's behavior you are interested in.

For example, if your app was designed in the MVC paradigm, then you might be able to drive the model from some non-android code.

There are some excellent mocking libraries for Java that might be able to help with this.  I'm a little familiar with Mockito, and it seems great to me, if you're looking for something that can replace components of your system to provide fabricated input to other components.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible much. Even though you kill all the other processes,it will take some time to load. The best option according to me is to keep it opened once you have started it(Don't close the window). You can also use BlueStacks App Player as an emulator.

Comment: i think he is looking for a way to speed up the application being emulated, not the emulator itself

Comment: well it's not much clear from the question he has posted.But the speed depends on his system.If he has a fast processor he can speed up the process of testing.It is possible to speed up the application if there are minor edits to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly , sorry.

The emulator is running actual ARM opcodes. It uses `qemu`, which is a virtualization system akin to a VirtualBox or VMWare, to accomplish this. That approach maximizes the fidelity between the emulator and real-world devices. Its cost is the ARM->Intel opcode conversion. The only way to significantly speed that up is to speed up the CPU that runs the emulator
http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/development/2011/10/speeding-up-the-android-emulator/ may help you

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible.

You can use the blue stack application as a workaround, for better performance. http://www.bluestacks.com/.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to accelerate the Android Emulator like

1. Using Snapshot
2. Use x86 intel hardware accelerator
3. Use 3rd party Emulator like BlueStacks

You can find a great discussion on the "Speed up Android Emulator" in this link: http://devcircle.blogspot.com/2013/02/speeding-up-your-android-emulator.html

Hope its help to overcome your problems.

Comment: 1) This is *not* what the question was asking; it was asking how to speed up the *time*. 2) You have failed to disclose that you are linking to your own blog.